# Highspeed with gearbox or low speed for brushless motor?

Tags: motor, brushless-motor

I'm attempting to control a small vehicle at relatively slow (.5 m/s - 1 m/s) speeds, but with extreme accuracy (1mm). For the drive system, I'm considering using brushless motors as they have a much greater power / volume ratio than I am able to find with brushed motors, especially at this small size.

I will be using wheels between 1" and 2" diameter, so the RPM I will be looking for is between 150 - 500 RPM at max. This would suggest either driving the motors at a low speed directly, or driving them at a high speed and gearing them down. As I understand it, both setups will give high torques, as brushless motors decrease torque with speed. With brushed motors, it's quite obvious that a gearbox is necessary as otherwise there is no torque in the system, but here the choice isn't as clear, which is why I am asking.

**tl;dr** Use brushless motors at high speed with gearbox or low speed (ungeared) for high torque / low speed / high precision application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Page 7 of [this PDF](http://www.beikimco.com/pdf/BLDC%20Product%20Guide.pdf) states that, "A permanent magnet DC brushless motor behaves like any permanent magnet DC brush motor."

You can read more about DC motor operation at [this MIT site](http://lancet.mit.edu/motors/motors3.html). I'm not sure if you've got a typo or what you're trying to say, but your question states, "brushless motors decrease torque with speed," after you state that using a gearbox and directly controlling the motor at low speed both, "will give high torques."

If you're looking to do speed control at a very low percentage of the motor's speed, I would suggest using a gearbox simply because you won't have much headroom to modulate the motor's speed. For example, assume the motor's [top speed is 50,000RPM](http://www.hobbypartz.com/30p-101-flash-aa-8900kv.html). You want to control the motor to 150RPM +/- 10RPM, which means that, if you're going to directly operate those motors at low speed with no gearbox, you need to be able to control the motor speed to within +/- 0.02% of the top speed. This will be hard, and you would probably actually want control within +/-1RPM, or 0.002% of top speed.

If you were to use a 100:1 gearbox, then top *output* speed becomes 500RPM, which means now you have to control motor speed to +/- 2%, or 0.2% for the +/-1RPM case, which suddenly becomes far more manageable.

The downside to using a gearbox is that they are physical, mechanical devices, meaning that they will have friction, backlash, and other drawbacks. Essentially you wind up paying a percentage of your motor's power for the advantage that speed becomes easier to control.

tl;dr - use gearboxes.